# react-native flatlist not rerendering

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Funny one this.

My flatlist rerenders on iOS but not android. That is - the flatlist renders and changes when I click on an item as I would expect from my code.

Flatlist code:

```
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.languageDataSource}
          extraData={this.state.refresh}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) =>

            <View>
              {(Platform.OS === 'android') ?
                <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() => this._onPress(item)} background={TouchableNativeFeedback.SelectableBackground()} >
                   <View> 
                    <MenuItem
                      item={item}
                      english={this.state.english}
                      navigation={this.props.navigation}
                      generateTestHook={this.props.generateTestHook.bind(this)}
                    />
                   </View> 
                </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                :
                <TouchableHighlight
                  onPress={() => this._onPress(item)}
                  underlayColor='gray'>
                  <MenuItem
                    item={item}
                    english={this.state.english}
                    navigation={this.props.navigation}
                    generateTestHook={this.props.generateTestHook.bind(this)}
                  />

                </TouchableHighlight>
              }
            </View>

          }
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
```

When we click we get

```
    _onGPSPress = (_click) => {

    this.state.gpsDataSource.forEach(element => {
      if (element.code == _click.code) { element.selected = true } else { element.selected = false;   this.setState({
        refresh: !this.state.refresh
      }) }
    });

   this.setState({
      refresh: !this.state.refresh
    })

    //Todo: appropriate server calls
  }
```

and it seems on logging that setstate does not work. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

This is to do with the way I am setting the state for the datasource which is:

```
gpsDataSource: [
        { selected: false, title: I18n.t('Settings_precise_11f271'), code: 'precise' },
        { selected: true, title: I18n.t('Settings_approximate_b23bbf'), code: 'approximate' },
        { selected: false, title: I18n.t('Settings_off_810357'), code: 'off' },
      ]
```

So how can I set the individual "selected" bools?

Comment: Have you checked the _click content? Have you try to log to see if _onGPSPress currently works?

Are you sure you want to setState inside the forEach and outside the forEach? This way you can change state twice ( true --> false and next false --> true).

Comment: Have you verified press event for android?

Comment: Press event works for Android

Comment: Click content is as expected; in fact the functionality works on iOS!

Answer (score 0):

If you feel there is an issue with setState then please try below code:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    refresh: !prevState.refresh
}));
```

Comment: Unfortunately works on iOS but not Android. What is going on?

Comment: Please try adding extraData={this.state} instead of using extraData={this.state.refresh}, so that list will automatically get refreshed.

Please refer this link for more details:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html